# Generate TCPDF output to a shared drive folder

Tags: php, pdf, path, directory, tcpdf

I'm trying to save my PDF file to a "Shared Folder", I'm using a configuration file to set the "Shared Folder" and then I just set the path inside the PHP file.

However it doesn't allow me to save with a "Shared Folder" path, it gives me the error:

```
Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

It works with `"C:/Path name/"`and I don't want to do this because I've not got access to the root folder.

**Value from the config file to create path name**

```
SharedFolder = //MIA_TEST/htdocs/SharedFolder
```

**My reading of file and Create folder structure:**

```
// Code to get values from config
function GetDictionaryOfUnsignedValues()
{
$fp = fopen("C:/ISOSEC/serverLicense.txt","r");

if ($fp ==  false)
    return null;

$UnsignedDataStarted    = false;
$UnsignedDataFinished = false;

$UnsignedData = "";

// Read the licence file line by line and extract signed data block as well as signature
while (($line = fgets($fp, 4096)) !== FALSE)
{
    if ($line == "ISOSEC NOT SIGNED:\n")
    {
        $UnsignedDataStarted = true;
        continue;
    }

    if ($UnsignedDataStarted and !$UnsignedDataFinished)
    {
        // When we come across an empty line (line length > 2), the signed dat block is finished
        if (strlen($line) > 2)
            $UnsignedData = $UnsignedData . $line;                  
        else
            $UnsignedDataFinished = true;           
    }
}

fclose($fp);

// Split the whole signed data block line by line
$ArrayOfLines = explode ("\n",$UnsignedData);

// Get the signed data into php easily accessible code - dctionary (associative array)
$UnsignedDataDictionary = array();

foreach ($ArrayOfLines as $line) 
{
    // Only lines containing ' = ' are valid lines
    if (strpos($line,' = ') !== false)
    {
        $keyValueArray = explode (" = ",$line);
        $UnsignedDataDictionary[$keyValueArray[0]] = $keyValueArray[1];
    }
}

if (count($UnsignedDataDictionary) < 1)
    return NULL;

return $UnsignedDataDictionary; 
}

// Create folder in folder
function createFolderInFolder($InputFolder, $newFolder)
{
if (!is_dir($InputFolder))
    return NULL;

$CreatedFolder = $InputFolder . '/' .$newFolder;

//we don't want to rewrite the folder with new one if it already exist
if (file_exists ($CreatedFolder))
    return $CreatedFolder;

$oldmask = umask(0);

if (mkdir($CreatedFolder, 0777))
{
    umask($oldmask);
    return $CreatedFolder;
}
else
    return NULL;
}



// Obtain shared folder from config file
// Then create output folder (or check if exist the output folder)

$ServerConfigDictionary = GetDictionaryOfUnsignedValues();
if ($ServerConfigDictionary == NULL)
    LogToLogFileAndFinishExecution("Discharge - Failed to obtain list of server configuration items from the server licence file");
if (!array_key_exists('SharedFolder', $ServerConfigDictionary))
    LogToLogFileAndFinishExecution("Discharge - Failed to obtain Shared folder location item from the server licence file");

// Get the shared folder location from the server config file
$SharedFolder = $ServerConfigDictionary['SharedFolder'];


// Check database connection, if not established, output an error and finish the script
if ($connection == NULL)
    LogToLogFileAndFinishExecution("Unable to establish database conection - unable to generate Postnatals");

if (($OutputFolder = createFolderInFolder($SharedFolder, "MIA - Digital Post Natal Records")) == NULL)
{
    LogMessageToServerLog($connection, 'Failed to create or find folder to store Discharges in shared directory', "ERROR", "Discharge.php");
    exit(0);
}
```

I'm using TCPDF for the generation of the PDF, here the line of code which generates the PDF

**PDF code1:**

```
//PDF Output
$pdf->Output($OutputFolderPath . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Forename'] . ' ' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Surname']  . '_' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['NHSID'] . ' ' . date('d_m_Y') . '.pdf'),'F');  // $OutputFolderPath . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Forename'] . ' ' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Surname']  . ' ' . date('d_m_Y h_i_s', time() . '.pdf','F');
```

**Response1:**

```
fopen(file:////MIA_TEST/htdocs/SharedFolder/MIA - Digital Post Natal Records/Fiona Appleton_1946546288 09_06_2015.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

**PDF Code 2: (Added realpath)**

```
$pdf->Output(realpath($OutputFolderPath) . ReplaceWindowsFileNameSpecialCharacters($Mother->PatientTableRecord['Forename'] . ' ' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Surname']  . '_' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['NHSID'] . ' ' . date('d_m_Y') . '.pdf'),'F');  // $OutputFolderPath . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Forename'] . ' ' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Surname']  . ' ' . date('d_m_Y h_i_s', time()) . '.pdf','F');
```

**Response 2:**

```
fopen(): remote host file access not supported, file://\\MIA_TEST\HTDOCS\SharedFolder\MIA - Digital Post Natal RecordsFiona Appleton_1946546288 09_06_2015.pdf
```

**PDF Code 3:**

```
// Worked
fopen($OutputFolderPath."Text.pdf", "w");

// Didn't work
$pdf->Output($OutputFolderPath . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Forename'] . ' ' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Surname']  . '_' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['NHSID'] . ' ' . date('d_m_Y') . '.pdf','F');  // $OutputFolderPath . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Forename'] . ' ' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Surname']  . ' ' . date('d_m_Y h_i_s', time()) . '.pdf','F'

// Works with no PDF content inside
fopen($OutputFolderPath . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Forename'] . ' ' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Surname']  . '_' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['NHSID'] . ' ' . date('d_m_Y') . '.pdf','F');  // $OutputFolderPath . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Forename'] . ' ' . $Mother->PatientTableRecord['Surname']  . ' ' . date('d_m_Y h_i_s', time()) . '.pdf','w');
```

**Response 3:**

```
fopen(file:////MIA_TEST/htdocs/SharedFolder/MIA - Digital Post Natal Records/Fiona Appleton_1946546288 09_06_2015.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can use this:

```
$savedOutput = file_get_contents('SavedOutput.pdf');
file_put_contents('newSavedOutput.pdf', $saveOutput);
```

I save the PDF into a folder, then get the content and save it to the shared folder

Answer (score 0):

If

```
//MIA_TEST/htdocs/SharedFolder
```

is a valid path. You should not be having any issues saving the PDF. PHP is not able to find the path you are specifying.

Try to do a simple

```
fopen("//MIA_TEST/htdocs/SharedFolder/sample.txt", "w");
```

If this works, your problem is solved. Please make sure the path is right. Also check if you have spaces in your destination path.

```
Output()
```

replaces spaces with underscores and removes sepcial characters. You might want to ensure everything is right wrt to these things.

http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1

Comment: I can't get the absolute path as it's for someone else, who give me access to the 'Shared Drive (Folder)' which I have to save the file in.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly is provided to you ?

Comment: On my test server, I've got access to everything. So i've had to make my own shared folder. However when I send the project across it'll only have access to the Shared drive through how i've done it in my code.

- In my code i'm able to make the folder "MIA - Digital Post Natal Records" but for some reason in the line of pdf output it fails to create the PDF 

- The actual creation of the folder structure works, it's the creation of the file seems to fail but works with a absolute path

Comment: are you able to do a fopen() for that path and write a file ?
if that works, saving your PDF should also work.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: I've updated my question to show you two ways i've tried now, and the response I get with it

Comment: You have an additional  forward slash in the path.
Try to open that path in your command prompt and if it works there, it will work here too.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to chat there. Please check my above comment.

Comment: I've updated my question for you, It's really weird that it's not working

Comment: Can you also add the response that you are getting ?

Comment: Updated, the response has been added in Response 3

Comment: What is the value of 
`$OutputFolderPath` ?

You are not doing the same in both the scenarios of 3. In the second scenario, there are spaces.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check again.